# Why is editing disabled on some posts?

Tags: discussion, support, edits, suggested-edits, quality-improvement

On some posts, the edit option is disabled like in the screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

I think that this is annoying because on many posts that I've seen where this happens, there are severe formatting problems that I would like to edit (for example the code is posted as a screenshot instead of code).

I'm sure that there is a good reason to this, but I would like to know what that reason is. What's the purpose of keeping people from editing posts with severe formatting problems?